# How to calculate L1 norm of an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I've couple of question related to l1 norm. Is it same as TV(Total Variation)? How to calculate L1 norm of an image in matlab? I did read the wiki page for TV, but it's way too complicated for me.

Answer (score 5):

The `L1` norm is the sum of absolute values:

```
l1norm = sum( abs( img(:) ) );
```

TV measures the gradients of the image and not the intensities directly.

Comment: how can I calculate TV of an image? And what does it imply?

Answer (score 2):

The L1 norm of an image/matrix can be calculated using the [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) function of MATLAB.

```
l1norm = norm(img(:), 1);
```